# Configuring Spring MVC REST to return only xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have configured an application that returns json and xml views depending on whats appended on the end of the url.

as per:

http://pfelitti87.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/rest-services-with-spring-3-xml-json.html

I want to re-configure it but only allow xml to be returned.

Not sure how to do that, everything i have done still returns json, when nothing is appended to the end

```
   @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
        public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver() {
            ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setOrder(1);
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setFavorPathExtension(true);
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setFavorParameter(true);
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setIgnoreAcceptHeader(false);
            Map<String, String> mediaTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mediaTypes.put("xml", "application/xml");
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
            List<View> defaultViews = new ArrayList<View>();
            defaultViews.add(xmlView());
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews);
            return contentNegotiatingViewResolver;
        }
```

so the output goes like this :

```
.../state.json    error no jsp page json

.../state.xml     works fine

.../state         error no jsp page
```

What i want is the the following two urls to return xml

```
.../state

.../state.xml
```

The above does not work..

and this is the controller mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/{id}/{ref}/state", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public state getState(...) {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a solution configured through xml;
- the controller

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/simpleEntity")
public class SimpleRestController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody SimpleEntity get() {
        return new SimpleEntity();
    }
```

}

the xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="marshaller" ref="xstream"/>
            <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xstream"/>
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>#{T(org.springframework.http.MediaType).TEXT_XML_VALUE}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="de.incompleteco.spring.web"/>

<bean id="xstream" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller"/>
```

here's a Configuration version

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("de.incompleteco.spring.web")
public class SimpleConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private XStreamMarshaller marshaller;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(getHttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);

    }

    public HttpMessageConverter<Object> getHttpMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        converter.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractMarshaller marshaller() {
        if (marshaller == null) {
            return new XStreamMarshaller();
        } else {
            return marshaller;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for that.. how about adding this to the controller  produces={"application/xml"}

Comment: yes - that can be done - a 'nicer' way to do it is `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE` - saves any spelling mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Remove jackson from classpath

Remove the entry `<entry key="json" value="application/json" />` from `mediaTypes` of `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`.

Remove the bean `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />` from `defaultViews` of `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`.

Comment: i have done that, removed the json.. but i cant it to default to xml when nothing is appended...